# A table left outer joining with itself: How does this work?

Tags: sql, database, join, design-patterns, database-design

I'm reading the book *SQL Antipatterns* and trying to understand its example of building a "tree" with a self-referential table such as

```
                         Comments
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  comment_id | parent_id | author |      comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------
       1          NULL     Fran      What's the cause of this bug?
       2            1      Ollie     I think it's a null pointer.
       3            2      Fran      No, I checked for that.
       4            1      Kukla     We need to check for invalid input.
       5            4      Ollie     Yes, that's a bug.
       6            4      Fran      Yes, please add a check.
       7            6      Kukla     That fixed it.
```

So the book says

> You can retrive a comment and its immediate children using a
>   relatively simple query:
>
> ```
> SELECT c1.*, c2.*
> FROM Comments c1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c2
>   ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
> ```

I'm trying to understand how this works. The way I've always understood left outer joins between a table `t1` and `t2` is that you take **all** the rows from `t1` and for the rows where the `ON` clause is not satisfied you fill in `NULL` for the columns from the second table. In this case there is only one table, but I can imagine that the query is taking place with two tables where the second one is a copy of the first. Still, I don't understand how that query returns

> two levels of the tree.

What exactly is the resulting table and can you walk me through the logic of how it is resulted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting table will be the following:

```
                         Comments
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  c1.comment_id | c1.parent_id | c1.author |  c1.comment                          | c2.comment_id | c2.parent_id | c2.author | c2.comment                         | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1               NULL      Fran         What's the cause of this bug?             2               1         Ollie        I think it's a null pointer.
       1               NULL      Fran         What's the cause of this bug?             4               1         Kukla        We need to check for invalid input. 
       2               1         Ollie        I think it's a null pointer.              3               2         Fran         No, I checked for that.                                                      
       3               2         Fran         No, I checked for that.                   NULL            NULL      NULL         NULL                                
       4               1         Kukla        We need to check for invalid input.       5               4         Ollie        Yes, that's a bug.                 
       4               1         Kukla        We need to check for invalid input.       6               4         Fran         Yes, please add a check.           
       5               4         Ollie        Yes, that's a bug.                        NULL            NULL      NULL         NULL                                
       6               4         Fran         Yes, please add a check.                  7               6         Kukla        That fixed it.
       7               6         Kukla        That fixed it.                            NULL            NULL      NULL         NULL
```

In the `ON` clause, we have `c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id`. This will mean that the "right" table (`c2`)'s `parent.id` will join with the "left" table (`c1`)'s `comment_id`.

The table branches out to itself by mapping each row with its child comments. The result on the right side (`c2`) will be all the children of `c1` entries, which repeat for each child. Since we're doing a left join, rows without children will simply return `NULL` on the `c2` columns.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct- yes you should think of it as a left join to a copy of itself.  The reason it represents one level of depth is because each row represents a comment, but it may have a link to a parent comment (parent_id) which means that you could translate this table to a tree to help visually understanding it.  Because you are left joining you are taking each comment and matching it to all its children.  If it doesn't have any children the child columns will be null (consequence of left join).  If you draw out a tree you can take each node and circle it plus all of its immediate children and you will see that is your result set.  If you joined again, you would go 2 levels deep and you would get the children's children etc.

Edit: added image (sorry poor art)  you should notice 7 circles (1 per row in the original table) and 9 resulting rows (the extra 2 are from comment 1 and 4 having 2 children each)

[image: 7 circles, 9 resulting rows]